# EF Core Average with no sequence

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem when from List want to do grouping by properties and take average or sum of specific properties I'm getting error Sequence does not contain elements. Than I put DefaultIfEmpty, than I get different error **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Code is like this:

```
var items = _repository.GetAllItems();
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(x=> new {Year = x.DateCreate.Year, Month = x.DateCreate.Month})
.Select(s=> new ItemForListViewModel(){
   Year = s.Key.Year,
   Month = s.Key.Month,
   AvgQnt = s.Where(x=>x.Price > 10).Average(x=>x.Qnt)
}).ToList();
```

Code from above gives error Sequence does not contain elements, than I change

```
 var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(x=> new {Year = x.DateCreate.Year, Month = x.DateCreate.Month})
    .Select(s=> new ItemForListViewModel(){
       Year = s.Key.Year,
       Month = s.Key.Month,
       AvgQntPrice10 = s.Where(x=>x.Price > 10).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x=>x.Qnt),
AvgQntPrice100 = s.Where(x=>x.Price > 100).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x=>x.Qnt
    }).ToList();
```

Than I get new error: **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

In database if I run query I get 0 for AvgQntPrice10 and example 15 for AvgQntPrice100  what is correct.

Regards,
Danijel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is of course that after `DefaultIfEmpty` the parameter `x` of `Average` calls can be `null` (the CLR default value for reference types).

Back to the original problem - *Sequence does not contain elements* exception when calling `Min`, `Max` or `Average` on empty collection. It can be solved correctly in two ways.

First is, instead of `DefaultIfEmpty().Average(selector)`, use the not so concise, but working combination `Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty().Average()`, e.g.

```
AvgQntPrice10 = s.Where(x => x.Price > 10).Select(x => x.Qnt).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
AvgQntPrice100 = s.Where(x => x.Price > 100).Select(x => x.Qnt).DefaultIfEmpty().Average()
```

Second (and my preferred) is to utilize the fact the nullable overloads of the `Min`, `Max` and `Average` methods do not throw *Sequence does not contain elements* exception for empty collection, but return `null` instead. So all you need is to cast the selector expression type to the corresponding nullable type, and optionally use the `??` on the aggregate method result to assign a special value for that case (like `0`).

For instance, if the type of the `Qnt` is `int` (if not, use the proper type), the above could be written as

```
AvgQntPrice10 = s.Where(x => x.Price > 10).Average(x => (int?)x.Qnt) ?? 0,
AvgQntPrice100 = s.Where(x => x.Price > 100).Average(x => (int?)x.Qnt) ?? 0
```